# Chromecast Stream from Android Phone to Laptop via Ad Hoc Network

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, hdmi, android, chromecast

I want to mirror the screen of my Android phone (HTC Sensation) on my laptop wirelessly.

Google Chromecast looks like a good solution to this - how would I set up an ad-hoc network so that I can view my phone's display on my laptop without a router? (I don't need internet connection)

Additionally, my laptop only has an HDMI out and not an HDMI in - can I plug the chromecast to my laptop via USB.

I found this tutorial but I'm not sure if its what I want:

http://pack3tlife.com/2013/11/18/ad-hoc-network-with-chromecast-and-windows-8/

I don't own a chromecast so can't test this.

Can anybody help me with this?

Comment: What version of android does your phone use? I don't *think* this is possible, but it might give people ideas on alternatives.

Comment: The HTC Sensation ships with Android 2.3.3 but I don't know if I updated it or not.

Comment: I did update it - it is now version 4.0.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using an Ad-Hoc network won't work if your Android phone does not support Ad-Hoc mode (properly), which in my experience are most Android phones.

You could fall back to a WiFi hotspot, e.g. provisioned by your phone, but this hogs *a lot* of power.

Another problem you get with a Chromecast but no HDMI-in will be the HDCP, so even if you managed to get a signal through some adapters, this probably won't work.

If you have a rooted phone, there are some alternatives like AndroidScreencast or a VNC server, but this *needs* the root access.

The Android version for TeamViewer could work on your phone, but that probably needs an internet connection to initialize the connection between your computer and your phone.

Comment: Also, the android teamvier client is just a tool to send screenshots.

Comment: @RoaldvanDoorn I have not tried Teamviewer Quicksupport, but the description says "remote control", so I assumed, it would work like the normal TV..

Comment: It isn't, I have tried a trial version of. It's more of a deluxe support-chat. The person behind a desktop can request screenshots from the android device, chat, send wifi instructions, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the "Airmirror" function of the Airdroid program/app.  See:

http://help.airdroid.com/customer/portal/articles/1784666-airmirror

Airdroid is a tool I discovered a while ago when I was trying to find a way to use my phone from my laptop (because I'm lazy and it's more convenient not to have to switch back and forth). At first I just thought it was only a website, but then I saw there's also a desktop program for it that has a mirroring application for the device. Here's a video I made of Airdroid in action: http://screencast.com/t/7dfW0WgSevvI

Comment: Can you expand your answer a little?  If/when the link breaks, your answer would be just a hint.  It would be much more useful to include the essential information here and use the link for attribution and further reading.  Thanks.

Comment: Sure, sorry.  Airdroid is a tool I discovered a while ago when I was trying to find a way to use my phone from my laptop (because I'm lazy and it's more convenient not to have to switch back and forth).  At first I just thought it was only a website, but then I saw there's also a desktop program for it that has a mirroring application for the device.  Here's a video:  http://screencast.com/t/7dfW0WgSevvI

Answer (score 0):

Forget it. The Chromecast requires an internet connection in order to work. You will not be able to set it up on a router, until it detects an internet connection.